# My VPS restarting every hour

Tags: linux, centos, vps, restart

Hello my server is restarting every hour, where the problem ?
Centos 6.6 with WHM/Cpanel

This my cronjob

```
root@server [/etc/cron.d]# crontab -l
0 6 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/exim_tidydb > /dev/null 2>&1
30 5 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/optimize_eximstats > /dev/null 2>&1
2,58 * * * * /usr/local/bandmin/bandmin
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bandmin/ipaddrmap
18 23 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/upcp --cron
0 1 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/cpbackup
0 2 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/bin/backup
35 * * * * /usr/bin/test -x /usr/local/cpanel/bin/tail-check && /usr/local/cpanel/bin/tail-check
45 */4 * * * /usr/bin/test -x /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/update_mailman_cache && /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/update_mailman_cache
30 */4 * * * /usr/bin/test -x /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/update_db_cache && /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/update_db_cache
30 */2 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/bin/mysqluserstore >/dev/null 2>&1
15 */2 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/bin/dbindex >/dev/null 2>&1
15 */6 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/autorepair recoverymgmt >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/cpanel/bin/dcpumon >/dev/null 2>&1
46 0 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/cgi/cpaddons_report.pl --notify
7,22,37,52 * * * * /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/bin/dnsqueue > /dev/null 2>&1
42 4 * * * /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/freshclam --quiet --no-warnings
```

Comment: Can you post the output of e.g. `last` so that times of the reboots are shown? That could be helpful to try to correlate.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your cron jobs I can see that this job runs every hour, so that is a good place to start looking:

```
35 * * * * /usr/bin/test -x /usr/local/cpanel/bin/tail-check && /usr/local/cpanel/bin/tail-check
```

Also, this job runs twice an hour, but they happen so close together that it might appear to occur only once. Check it out next:

```
2,58 * * * * /usr/local/bandmin/bandmin
```

If you can, I would just comment out these 2 jobs for a few hours and see if that solves your problem. If it does then you know one of these is causing the reboot.